# Is sodium percarbonate artificial?

Tags: home-experiment

If I add sodium percarbonate to my natural laundry soap recipe, can I still claim "No Artificial Anything"?
I know it's used in many "natural" products, but is it considered an "artificial ingredient"?
I don't want to make any false claims with my product.

thank you!

Comment: I think this is more a question of what you're allowed to do under your local regulatory agencies than it is a question of the chemistry. If it were left up to chemists, "organic" products would be completely different from what they are now.

Comment: Yeah, maybe a better fit for Law SE. Just don't write "all natural, organic, and chemical free" on it and our heads won't explode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not actually about solid chemistry. Instead it depends on local/national laws.

Comment: There are no "laws" that govern cleaning products...unfortunately. Companies can poison us with anything and do not even have to tell us what they are using. Im just trying to get solid information to market honestly.   Thank you.

Comment: @jerryhere I don't find the claim 'no artificial ingredients' to be informative at all. The distinction of 'artificial' vs. 'natural' has no bearing on safety. The most potent toxins are from nature, yet unsafe. A washing machine is artificial, yet your product depends on its use. I suggest you find a better way to market your product than a 'no artificial anything' claim.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is artificial. Sodium carbonate is a substance that occurs in nature, even though any of it is most likely manufactured.

Sodium percarbonate, on the other hand, does not occur in nature and it has to be manufactured. It is an oxidiser, and oxidisers don't occur in nature normally. That's a problem for you, because oxidisers (aka bleach) are desired in laundry applications.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  I felt that would be the answer but wanted to confirm with others that know more than me in chemistry.

Comment: Would Oxalic acid be considered the same....artificial?

Comment: @jerryhere what if it is a substance that occurs naturally, but the one you would probably use is bought somewhere and manufactured? There are so many substances that occur in nature, but it's easier and cheaper to manufacture them artificially. Does that make them any worse? Is the fact that a substance is "not artificial", whatever that means, make it any safer or better? Absolutely not. You need to have strict definition of what is "artificial", and we're not the place to look for that answer.